# Is there some Selenium web driver analogue for automated testing contents of HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, selenium, canvas, automated-tests, pixi.js

Currently trying to maintain automated testing of a game. It was made using Pixi.js and launches within HTML5 Canvas.
Is there a method to provide something similar to Selenium's actions (click, type etc), accessors (storeText, storeValue etc) and assertions (assertText, assertValue etc) for contents of HTML5 Canvas? Is there a method to find particular object within Canvas by some locator? Finally is there something like Canvas driver ala Selenium web driver?
I've heard that there is something similar to DOM tree for Canvas but failed to find much info about it.

Comment: have you find something?

Comment: @Karla kind of. There is no any specific tool for this task that I've found. But visual testing tools are quite capable for this task too. There are plenty of them in the market currently (free and paid), I would suggest to check SikuliX and PyAutoGUI (both free and open source).